# solo.searchButton always return true (Android 2.3.6 with robotium)

Tags: android, robotium

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. i want to use this " solo.searchButton("Show pictures"); " for search button on current screen. and if exist then perform some action, if not present then perform some other action.
2. even if this button not in current screen, it returns true.

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**

if button with name "Show pictures" exist on screen then and then " solo.searchButton("Show pictures"); " returns true, otherwise it should return false.

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**

Samsunt Galaxy Ace,
Android 2.3.6 (GB),
library : robotium-solo-3.4.1

Eclipse (with Windows 7)

**Please provide any additional information below.**

i test it on android 4.0.3 (ICS) and 4.1.1

(JB)solo.searchButton always return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use: searchButton(String text, boolean onlyVisible) instead. The issue you are experiencing is that the view is there however it is invisible and therefore you can not see it. Hope this helps!

Comment: if(solo.searchButton("Show pictures"))
{
  solo.clickOnButton(0);
  Log.v(TAG,"Click On Start");
  solo.sleep(2000);
}

above function always return true for me.


if(solo.searchButton("Show pictures",true))
{
  solo.clickOnButton(0);
  Log.v(TAG,"Click On Start");
  solo.sleep(2000);
}

now above finction with "true" arguement
return true if and only if "Show pictures" button found on screen.
Thanks very much Royston Pinto.